# Storing scraped data from web page to json object using java

Tags: java, json

Iam scraping the mobiles data from the web page , I need mobile name and price of all the mobiles of that page into json object below is my code:

```
Elements mobilename = document.select(
    "#products div.product-unit div.pu-title ");
Elements price = document.select(
    "#products div.product-unit div.pu-price div.pu-final span.fk-font-17");

for(Element url1:mobilename)
{
    text=url1.text();
    System.out.println(text);
    for(Element b:price)
    {
        text1= b.text();

        System.out.println(text1);

        arr1.add(text1);
        arr1.add(text);
    }

    pa.put("price",text1 );
    pa.put("name", text);
    obj7.add(pa);
}
json.put("mobile:", obj7);
```

I am trying for the following out put for all the mobiles in a page:

```
{"mobile:":[{"price":"Rs. ","name":""}
```

Comment: Use some libary for working with json eg [org.json](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: iam using json-simple-1.1.1.jar